# number of tokenized sentences does not match number of sentences in text

Tags: nlp, nltk, tokenize, sentence

I have some problems with the `nltk.sent_tokenize` function.

My text (that I want to tokenize) consist of 54116 sentences that are separated by a dot. I removed other punctuation.
I would like to tokenize my text on a sentence level by using `nltk.sent_tokenize`.

However, if I apply `tokenized_text = sent_tokenize(mytext)`, the length of `tokenized_text` is only 51582 instead of 54116.

Any ideas, why this could happen?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

This would typically happen because the model for Sentence Boundary Detection can not detect all sentence boundaries correctly — typically limited by its accuracy, which would be of the order of 97%-99%. That said, since you are claiming that the corpus has sentences strictly separated by a "dot", you may simply split it on '.', provided there are no abbreviations like Prof. or Dr. or Sr. etc. You may like to refer to https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C12-2096.pdf for further details.